# Angular switched buttons logic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple problem, but I'm a beginner so I can't understand the logic,

I have 2 buttons one and two, when I click on one I would like to display instead of one and two the other buttons so three and four? made a switch.

What is the best way to do this? Is using if else in the HTML correct or should we move this logic to the ts file?

Thanks in advance.

**html**

```
<div *ngIf="!isButtons">
  <button> one</button>
  <button> two</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button> three</button>
  <button> four</button>
</div>
```

**ts.file**

```
isButtons:boolean = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is simple enough to remain in the template, you don't need any more code in your component. A simple `(click)` and a `<ng-template>` will do the trick:

```
<div *ngIf="!isButtons; else threeAndFour">
  <button (click)="isButtons=true"> one</button>
  <button> two</button>
</div>

<ng-template #threeAndFour>
    <div>
        <button> three</button>
        <button> four</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your code example, you can just

- add `*ngIf="isButtons"` to the second `div` so you'll handle the final state
- add the click handler on the button you want to trigger the change: `(click)="isButtons = true"`

Final snippet:

```
<div *ngIf="!isButtons">
  <button (click)="isButtons = true"> one</button>
  <button> two</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isButtons">
  <button> three</button>
  <button> four</button>
</div>
```

Jeremy Thille's answer is just as good, but most likely not something a beginner can handle (`ng-template` and more complex `*ngIf` usage).